# Can't compile pivoted QR decomposition with Eigen (through RcppEigen)

Tags: rcpp

As quite an expert R user with no knowledge in C++ and OOP in general, I would like to EXPLORE the QR decomposition with the Eigen matrix algebra library (through the R package RccpEigen), because of its expected high performance. 
When I run the following code snippet (the first example from [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html) - I added the first 2 lines, which however do not affect outputs) through 'sourceCpp':

```
sourceCpp(code='
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
   Matrix3f A;
   Vector3f b;
   A << 1,2,3,  4,5,6,  7,8,10;
   b << 3, 3, 4;
   cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
   cout << "Here is the vector b:\n" << b << endl;
   Vector3f x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);
   cout << "The solution is:\n" << x << endl;
}
')
```

I get the following (long, sorry) message:

```
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/include" - 
DNDEBUG   -I"C:/Users/W10PRO~1/DOCUME~1/R/WIN-LI~1/3.6/Rcpp/include" - 
I"C:/Users/W10PRO~1/DOCUME~1/R/WIN-LI~1/3.6/RCPPEI~1/include" - 
I"C:/Users/W10PRO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RTMPO2~1/SOURCE~1.3"        -O2 -Wall  
-mtune=core2 -c file2b0301f29d8.cpp -o file2b0301f29d8.o
file2b0301f29d8.cpp:16:11: warning: missing terminating " character
cout << "Here is the matrix A:

file2b0301f29d8.cpp:16:3: error: missing terminating " character
cout << "Here is the matrix A:

file2b0301f29d8.cpp:17:1: warning: missing terminating " character
 " << A << endl;
file2b0301f29d8.cpp:17:1: error: missing terminating " character
file2b0301f29d8.cpp:18:11: warning: missing terminating " character
cout << "Here is the vector b:
       ^
file2b0301f29d8.cpp:18:3: error: missing terminating " character
cout << "Here is the vector b:

file2b0301f29d8.cpp:19:1: warning: missing terminating " character
 " << b << endl;

file2b0301f29d8.cpp:19:1: error: missing terminating " character
file2b0301f29d8.cpp:21:11: warning: missing terminating " character
cout << "The solution is:

file2b0301f29d8.cpp:21:3: error: missing terminating " character
cout << "The solution is:

file2b0301f29d8.cpp:22:1: warning: missing terminating " character
 " << x << endl;

file2b0301f29d8.cpp:22:1: error: missing terminating " character
file2b0301f29d8.cpp: In function 'int main()':
file2b0301f29d8.cpp:20:12: error: expected primary-expression before 'x'
Vector3f x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);
        ^
file2b0301f29d8.cpp:23:1: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
}

make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:215: file2b0301f29d8.o] 
Error 1
Error in sourceCpp(code = "\n// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]\n#include 
<RcppEigen.h>\n#include <iostream>\n#include <Eigen/Dense>\nusing namespace 
std;\nusing namespace Eigen;\n\n// [[Rcpp::export]]\nint main()\n{\n  
Matrix3f A;\n  Vector3f b;\n  A << 1,2,3,  4,5,6,  7,8,10;\n  b << 3, 3, 4;\n  
cout << \"Here is the matrix A:\n\" << A << endl;\n  cout << \"Here is the 
vector b:\n\" << b << endl;\n  Vector3f x = 
A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);\n  cout << \"The solution is:\n\" << x << 
endl;\n}\n") : 
Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

This is my R/C++ configuration (no gcc compiler?):

```
library(Rcpp)            # 1.0.3
library(RcppEigen)       # v. 0.3.3.7.0
RcppEigen:::eigen_version(FALSE) 
3     3     7 
find_rtools()
[1] TRUE
evalCpp("2+2")
[1] 4
has_compiler()
[1] TRUE
check_compiler()
[1] TRUE
check_build_tools()
>Your system is ready to build packages!
Sys.which("make")
"C:\\Rtools\\bin\\make.exe" 
Sys.getenv('PATH')
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R- 3.6.3\\bin\\x64;C:\\Rtools\\bin; etc
system('gcc -v')
127

sessionInfo()
> R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
> attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] pkgbuild_1.0.6      devtools_2.3.0      usethis_1.6.0       inline_0.3.15       
RcppEigen_0.3.3.7.0
[6] Rcpp_1.0.3         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
....
```

Any help, please? [Why "system('gcc -v')" gives 127?]

Comment: That's not how it works here. First you show us what you tried, then you can ask for help if it doesn't work. Edit your question, and please read some of this:https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: The code in your question also errors for me but when I save the code to a script and load it using `sourceCpp` it executes. Have you tried that? ps you  are missing a `//[[Rcpp::export]]` and the general advice is to use `Rcpp::Rcout`

Comment: ... if you want to use `sourceCpp=(code=...` you will need to escape the newlines i.e. use `\\n`

Comment: Thanks @user20650, from a script it does work!

Comment: Good stuff Antoniio. It should also work using the code, as in your question, if you change the `\n` for `\\n`

Comment: How can I change it? I didn't actually put any \n, either.

Comment: @user20650: the '<-' R operator automatically places \n at beginning of each new line of my C++ source code (in the 'src' R character vector); so I wrote: src<-sub("\n","\\n",src, fixed = T) to turn each \n into \\n, and then sourceCpp(src), but compile does not work.... [on Windows 10]

Comment: There is a `\n` in the line `"Here is the matrix A:\n"` . When Rcpp writes out the code to a tempfile (using writeLines) this gets interpreted as a newline and so splits that line so that the quotes `" "` are on different lines --> hence all the errors in your question. If you use `"Here is the matrix A:\\n"` it should be fine (was with me)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @user20650. I hadn't understood your previous comment. Now it works with both versions.

Comment: you're welcome ..